# Smarty Conditionals strings

Tags: smarty

I need to create a single string in SMARTY from two as below

```
{$value.b64id} = ?type=1&id=aWQ9
```

this is what I have got so far, cant seem to get anywhere. I think the quote marks are messing me up!!

```
{assign var='controls' value='<a style="color: red;" href="http://example.com'|cat:{$value.b64id}|cat:'">click Me</a>'}
```

so what I want from the end of it

```
{$controls} = <a style="color: red;" href="http://example.com?type=1&id=aWQ9">click Me</a>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you only need to use delimiters for variables if you want to display them in the template. When you're using variables inside a smarty function that's not necessary, so

```
|cat:{$value.b64id}
```

should be

```
|cat:$value.b64id
```

However, if you need to compose a string to reuse it several times, it's probably better to use {[capture](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl)}

```
{capture "controls"}
<a style="color: red;" href="http://example.com{$value.b64id}">click Me</a>
{/capture}
```

and then just use {$controls}

Comment: Thanks not tested yet, but what if controls already contained a value. how to append this to {$controls}

Comment: This worked, many thanks, so close... - {assign var='controls' value='<a style="color: red;" href="http://example.com'|cat:$value.b64id|cat:'">click Me</a>'}